# How do i add this 'Scanned Effect' on my CIImage Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage, core-image

**The first image is the image using my phone. The one under it is the Photoshopped version of the first one. I adjusted some levels on that image. Any idea how I can do this in Swift?**
[image]

Comment: Very broad and unfocused question... *"I adjusted some levels on that image."* ... Describe what you did in Photoshop to get that result. Might help you to review [ask].

Comment: I just adjusted the brightness, contrast, vibrance.

Comment: Well, ummm, yes... you "adjusted some levels"... what I'm asking is: **what levels did you adjust, and to what values?** If you say *"I adjusted brightness by +25"* someone might be able to tell you how to use `CIColorControls` to adjust brightness by +25. If you say *"I adjusted contrast by +90"* someone might be able to tell you how to use `CIColorControls` to adjust contrast by +90. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

Since iOS 13, Core Image provides a new [`CIDocumentEnhancer`](https://cifilter.io/CIDocumentEnhancer/) filter that basically does what Notes does when scanning a document.

If you want more control, you can probably also use a simple [`CIColorControls`](https://cifilter.io/CIColorControls/) filter for adjusting contrast and brightness.

Comment: ANY idea how I can do that automatically. Every image that I take inside my application has different exposure, brightness, contrast etc. I was wondering what kind of a check should I perform on that image so I could apply the right amounts of enhancements. I did read about CIColorControls. I even tried it and its pretty good but I'm unsure of what levels I should use since every image is different. Lemme know if there is something like that. Thank you.